# Donut Tutorial -- How to fix deleted icing

Tags: mesh

I accidentally deleted one of the downward dripping ends of the icing mesh.
I tried finding my own fix for about half an hour but at this point I would just like to get back to the tutorial.

Thanks for any and all help, stay safe.

[image: Red is problem area. Green is desired effect/look.]

Comment: hello, how does the mesh look like? maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi, it should be uploaded now. Thanks, didn't know about that feature.

Comment: you need to share the link it gives you   ;)

Comment: Oh sorry, of course, haha. https://blend-exchange.com/b/jgD1XYmS
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you've cut a hole here, but you can fill it.

First you have overlapping vertices, switch to *Edit* mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), enable transparency (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>), select all the bottom vertices with the box selection (<kbd>B</kbd>) and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* in order to join the overlapping vertices here:

[image]

Disable the *Propotional Editing* option (<kbd>O</kbd>), extrude down the edge loops  (<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) and scale it down:

[image]

At last fill the face with <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Thank you for explaining things SO clearly.

And thank you for your time and help. Stay safe!